# Is useCallback() on direct dom elements (like <input>) useless?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was just looking at a code review that asked me to remove a `useCallback` for a click handler that I had on an `<input>`

I know that we can do `useCallback` to check in other components when doing `Memo`, but what about a direct HTML node?

My question would be: Does React virtualdom re-mount the whole tree (in the real DOM) or just the parts that changed?

i.e. if I have this

```
const handleClick = useCallback(() => {}, []);

return <div className={classNameFromProps}>
   <input onClick={handleClick}>
   <SomeComponent someProp={somePropFromLocalState}>
</div>
```

1. If `classNameFromProps` changes, does it trigger a forced remount of all children in the DOM? (not just virtual dom)
2. If only `somePropFromLocalState` changes, the component re-renders due to a local state change, but does react also re-mount in the DOM the `<input>` ?

Comment: I can answer 2: only `SomeComponent` is re-rendered; the other components (parent and sibling) don't change. I'm not so sure about 1.

Comment: this is almost undoubtedly a premature optimization. unless `input` is inside a tight loop like `requestAnimationFrame`, then it probably doesn't matter if you memoize the closure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React's [reconciliation steps](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) will do a good job at reusing the elements that already exist in the DOM if the React code isn't badly written in such a way to mess with it. (For example, in contrast, if you use `<div key={Math.random()}`, React will re-create that `<div>` each time.)

> If classNameFromProps changes, does it trigger a forced remount of all children in the DOM? (not just virtual dom)

React will re-run the component, examine what React components it returns, and then compare that to the components that were returned the last time that component was run, including props, children, and nested components. But only the values that are different will result in a change to the actual DOM. In this case, if `classNameFromProps` is the only change, the existing elements will all be preserved, but React may do something like `.className = classNameFromProps` under the hood.

Similarly, if you do not memoize the callback, then

```
<input onClick={handleClick}>
```

will result in the click listener (but not the input) being re-created every render.

That said, in almost all situations, the re-creation of such a listener on a native DOM element is not worth considering at all - whether you memoize the callback or not won't have any visible effect.

> If only somePropFromLocalState changes, the component re-renders due to a local state change, but does react also re-mount in the DOM the  ?

During reconciliation, it will see that the input from the previous render matches the input from the next render, so the `<input>` won't get re-created. If the input click handler is memoized, the listener won't be removed and re-added to the input either.